# Gantry v4 - disable Cache

Tags: joomla, frameworks

Is there any other way to disable the cache in gantry besides this core hack?

http://internet-inspired.com/wrote/tutorials/disabling-gantrys-less-compiler/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla template frameworks and not programming as defined for StackOverflow, it may get a better result on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Why do you want to disable the LESS compiler, it only runs when needed (e.g. LESS files change, cache file not found etc) not on every request?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I don't think Gantry itself as a framework caches files. If you're using a Rockettheme template that was part of a demo package (includes the Joomla CMS, template and extensions), then you most likely have the RokBooster plugin which
 is caching the files. Have a look to see if this plugin is installed, else check if you have any core Joomla settings that are enabled for caching.

Comment: I am using gantry with the default gantry template. no rokbooster